# Does laravel has any gems to extend or modify functionality?

Tags: laravel-5

Does laravel has gems like as ruby on rails have? Like, for signup flow ruby on rails has "devise" gem. Does laravel has anything like that?

Comment: You're probably looking for [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/) and [Packagist](https://packagist.org/). Packages on Packagist are for _PHP_, but not necessarily Laravel, much like Gems are for _Ruby_, but not necessarily Rails. (Note that questions asking us to find or recommend off-site resources are off-topic here. You can read about what's on-topic in the [help/on-topic]).

Answer (score 2):

There is no built-in package manager for Laravel but you can use reference like: https://packalyst.com . Here you can find all available packages for Laravel. All of them can be installed with Composer - php package manager. There is detail description how to install every pack in Packalyst.

If you want to have auth in Laravel you have two options. To do it manually, or to use the built-in module for authentication. You can run

```
php artisan make:auth
```

in the main project directory. This will add the required views and routes in the Laravel file structure in order to use the auth. Better to run this command on fresh installation. See this for detailed step by step authentication with Laravel 5: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authentication#authentication-quickstart